# Override NewRelic config file used by Cloud Foundry java build pack

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, newrelic, buildpack

I have a Spring Boot application deployed in Cloud Foundry, using the standard [Java build pack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/releases/tag/v3.6). Since the app is bound to NewRelic, the build pack injects a NewRelic agent into the environment.

NewRelic documentation talks about adding a `newrelic.yml` file next to the agent jar location to customize instrumentation behavior. In the CF scenario, can it be located in the classpath of the deployed Spring Boot jar? How do I enable this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the CF scenario, can it be located in the classpath of the deployed Spring Boot jar? How do I enable this behavior?

I don't know about that, but two things you can do:

1. Specify additional configuration options for the NewRelic agent through your bound user provided service.

   https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-new_relic_agent.md#user-provided-service-optional

   > (Optional) Any additional entries will be applied as a system property appended to -Dnewrelic.config. to allow full configuration of the agent.
2. If you were to fork the Java build pack, you could overlay your own configuration file.

   https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-new_relic_agent.md#additional-resources

   Your custom file would go here:  https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/resources/new_relic_agent/newrelic.yml

You probably don't want to fork the build pack though as that creates a whole mess of other problems.

I guess a third option might be to use a `.profile.d` script, but that's a pain with Java apps because you have to put the files at the root of your JAR file.  It could work though.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html#profile

Hope that helps!